# Genymotion 2.1.1 API 18 VM gives AOSP Stopped error after GAPPS flash

Tags: android, genymotion

After flashing ARM Transalation and GAPPS from this tutorial : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952, "***Unfortunately AOSP Stopped***" message flashes every time. As a result Keyboard input is stopped, I cannot type anything. Signed into Google Play with great difficulty after copy pasting username password from a txt file. But still the problem persists after repeated reboots. Also I have tried fresh install numerous times, but still the same issue.

Also, back button doesn't work after Gapps flash. I have downloaded and tried both Gapps from mirrors too (*gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip* and *gapps-jb-20130813-signed_0.zip*, both 97MB files).

Need to mention though, only drag and drop just copies the files in Download directory in this new version of Genymotion, so had to flash both zips via adb. (*adb push ./system /system*)

Please help!

Comment: using adb to install things already unpacked on your development machine will probably fail as the ownership of various files (and probably permissions as well) would be distorted

Comment: You MUST use the flash feature from genymotion, installing files manually should not been necessary. Check that your donwnload is not corrupted by computing MD5 from 20130813-signed.zip and comparing it with value from http://goo.im/gapps

Comment: @pcans the problem is I cannot flash by the genymotion feature... the file just copies itself to a folder and does nothing!

Comment: @ChrisStratton same answer to you too

Comment: It has been explained why the method you are tying to apply will not work. But this doesn't really sound like a software development question to begin with.  You should probably ask for help from whoever's instructions you are following.